# Datascraping using Python - result is an empty <main></main>

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml, program-entry-point

I'm experimenting with datascraping a website as part of an internship using Python without using lxml, my code looks like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests

# Start the session
session = requests.Session()

# Create the payload
payload = {'email':'*********',
          'password':'********'
         }

# Post the payload to the site to log in
s = session.post("********************", data=payload)

url_to_scrape = "*******************"

page = urlopen(url_to_scrape)
print("printing page")
print(page)
html_bytes = page.read()
html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
print("printing html")
print(html)
```

This returns some of the websites information but most importantly nothing from the main, what I'm receiving from the main-part looks like this:

```
 <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <main id="wrap" ui-view=""></main>
```

But what I'm expecting is this:

```
<main id="wrap" ui-view="" class="ng-scope"><nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ng-scope" ng-class="navColorClass" ng-controller="MainMenuController" scroll-to-top="">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#servicedesk-navbar" aria-expanded="false" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
...
...
...
...
```

How can I get the expected output?

Comment: I suggest you try constructing the URL and its query parameters (email & password) and try it in your favourite browser and see what happens

Comment: As you did not share resources to reproduce your task, it's hard to point out what is missing. But, you may want to look at chrome developer tools or similar to see if what you are expecting is returned by the request/endpoint you're following. Also, note that it could be generated by some js/ajax. Try to disable js in your browser and look if content changes.